# How to travel x (e.g. 10) miles and get new co-ordinate having direction towards another location?

Tags: coordinate-system, distance

[image]

I'm trying to create a large but optimal circle that covers two intersecting circles. For that, I need to calculate new radius and new center point. I'm able to get the optimum radius by how can I get the new center point coordinate? I think we need to travel some X miles from one point to another. I have the calculation for X miles, but how to get the coordinate?

See below illustration. I have points A and B as geo coordinates. I wanted to travel x miles (let's say 10 miles) from Point A to Point B and get the co-ordinate of point P.

We can easily get the midpoint coordinates by (x1 + x2) / 2 formula which is 50% traveled from A to B but what if I want to travel 10% from point A towards point B?

[image]

Comment: Which CRS are you using? How large will the distances be? What data do you already have? What software are you working with? Is this a theoretical exercise? Do you care about geoids and earth curvature?

Comment: @Erik I'm using Google Map and when I say geo-coordinate means Earth is involved but I don't care if it's not perfectly round or spherical.

Comment: For a pt some fraction "a" from X1 to X2, just compute X1 + a *(X2-X1).